# how to get current running application in PoSh

Tags: powershell

How to get current running application in PoSh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `Get-Process` to get the application.

```
Get-Process applicationName
```

Answer (score 1):

SessionState.Applications (powershell 2.0 SDK)